# iOS (iPhone/iPad) SDK - Application not changing orientation

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, sdk

In my custom Tab Bar Application, the orientation never seems to change, even if I force rotate the status bar. Here is my code in my AppDelegate:

AppDelegate.h:

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import "MBProgressHUD.h"

    @class exampleViewContoller;
    @class example1ViewController;
    @class example2ViewController;
    @class example3ViewController;
    @class example4ViewController;

    @interface <appname>AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, MBProgressHUDDelegate> {
        UIWindow *window;
        UITabBarController *rootController;
        exampleViewContoller *viewController;
        example1ViewController *viewController1;
        example2ViewController *viewController2;
        example3ViewController *viewController3;
        example4ViewController *viewController4;
        NSMutableData *responseData;
        NSMutableArray *tweets;
        MBProgressHUD *HUD;
    }

    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBarController *rootController;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet exampleViewContoller *viewController;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet example1ViewController *viewController1;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet example2ViewController *viewController2;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet example3ViewController *viewController3;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet example4ViewController *viewController4;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *tweets;

    @end
```

AppDelegate.m:

```
    #import "<appname>AppDelegate.h"
    #import "exampleViewContoller.h"
    #import "example1ViewController.h"
    #import "example2ViewController.h"
    #import "example3ViewController.h"
    #import "example4ViewController.h"
    #import "SBJson.h"
    #define TMP NSTemporaryDirectory()

    @implementation <appname>AppDelegate

    @synthesize window = _window;
    @synthesize rootController;
    @synthesize viewController;
    @synthesize viewController1;
    @synthesize viewController2;
    @synthesize viewController3;
    @synthesize viewController4;
    @synthesize tweets;

    #pragma mark -
    #pragma mark Application lifecycle

    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
        CGFloat width = self.rootController.view.bounds.size.width;
        CGFloat height = self.rootController.view.bounds.size.height;
        UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, width, height)];
        UIImage *imageView = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TabBarBackground.png"];
        UIColor *kMainColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:imageView];

        [v setBackgroundColor:kMainColor];
        [kMainColor release];

        [self.rootController.tabBar insertSubview:v atIndex:0];
        [imageView release];
        [v release];

        responseData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
        tweets = [NSMutableArray array];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
                         [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=ENTER_USER_HERE&count=20"]];
        [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

        NSAssert(nil != self.rootController, @"tab bar controller not hooked up!");

        BOOL iPad = NO;
#ifdef UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM
        iPad = (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad);
#endif

        if (iPad) {
            self.viewController = [[[exampleViewContoller alloc] initWithNibName:@"exampleViewController_iPad" bundle:nil] autorelease];
            self.viewController1 = [[example1ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"example1ViewController_iPad" bundle:nil] autorelease];
            self.viewController2 = [[[example2ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"example2ViewController_iPad" bundle:nil] autorelease];
            self.viewController3 = [[[example3ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"example3ViewController_iPad" bundle:nil] autorelease];
            self.viewController4 = [[[example4ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"example4ViewController_iPad" bundle:nil] autorelease];
        } else {
            self.viewController = [[[exampleViewContoller alloc] initWithNibName:@"exampleViewContoller_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];
            self.viewController1 = [[[example1ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"example1ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];
            self.viewController2 = [[[example2ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"example2ViewController2_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];
            self.viewController3 = [[[example3ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"example3ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];
            self.viewController4 = [[[example4ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"example4ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];
        }
            self.rootController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.viewController, self.viewController4, self.viewController1, self.viewController3, self.viewController2, nil];

        [viewController release];
        [viewController1 release];
        [viewController2 release];
        [viewController3 release];
        [viewController4 release];

#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_4_0
        self.window.rootViewController = self.rootController;
#else
        [self.window addSubview:rootController.view];
#endif
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:viewController.view];
        [viewController.view addSubview:HUD];
        [HUD show:NO];

        HUD.delegate = self;

        HUD.labelText = @"Loading";


        return YES;
    }

//[---CODE CLIP---]

    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didChangeStatusBarOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)oldStatusBarOrientation {
        CGFloat width = self.rootController.view.bounds.size.width*2;
        CGFloat height = self.rootController.view.bounds.size.height;
        UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, width, height)];
        UIImage *imageView = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TabBarBackground.png"];
        UIColor *kMainColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:imageView];

        [v setBackgroundColor:kMainColor];
        [kMainColor release];
        [self.rootController.tabBar insertSubview:v atIndex:0];
        [imageView release];
        [v release];

    }

    - (void)hudWasHidden {
        [HUD removeFromSuperview];
    }

//[---CODE CLIP---]

    - (void)dealloc
    {
        [_window release];
        [rootController release];
        [HUD release];
        [super dealloc];
    }

    @end
```

The problem is that when I rotate the device in iOS Simulator, the application won't rotate. Any ideas would be much appreciated!

**UPDATE**

I have also noticed that the launch image is also not rotating (for iPad that is - iPhone doesn't do landscape launch images).

**NOTE FOR JMANS**

I overrode UITabBarController:

```
@implementation UITabBarController (MyApp)

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    if(self.selectedIndex==4) 
        return (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
    else
        return (toInterfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}
@end
```

Comment: did you check if the Portrait orientation is locked in the simulator (Double press the home button and swipe on right the multitask bar to reveal the controls from the left side. There is an orientation lock control)

Comment: @Bobj-C - No that isn't the problem but thanks for answering! It seems that the iOS Simulator can't have a locked orientation as everytime I click it, it says "Portrait Orientation Unlocked".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would start by including this in all of your view controllers:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}
```

Also, make sure that you are supporting multiple orientations in your Info.plist.

Comment: Thanks, turned out I had to return YES for ALL of the viewControllers. Even the ones I don't want to rotate! Although I'm stuck on how to make one or two tabs not rotate while still allowing the other ones to rotate.

Comment: So do you want the tab view always to rotate, but the content to only rotate sometimes? Or do you want the tab view to rotate based on what tab is selected? You could set a variable somewhere (like your App Delegate) that specifies whether certain orientations are currently enabled, and then check that variable before returning from the various shouldAutorotate... methods.

Comment: See the bottom of my question.

Comment: This was a hair-puller -- thanks for the tip!  I had it all working, then added a new view controller to the storyboard and suddenly, it quit rotating!  The other thing you have to make sure of is that "Supported interface orientations" is set up properly in the <MyApp>-info.plist.

Answer (score 4):

Tab Bar Controllers and View Rotation

Tab bar controllers support a portrait orientation by default and do not rotate to a landscape orientation unless all of the contained view controllers support such an orientation. When a device orientation change occurs, the tab bar controller queries its array of view controllers. If any one of them does not support the orientation, the tab bar controller does not change its orientation.

Comment: This worked after so many other solutions failed...Thanks! Kudos!