# tabbar based application won't rotate at all

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

My tab bar based application won't rotate at all. I've done all the configuration needed without luck. All my controllers override the:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}
```

and in the `viewDidLoad` method i have set the properties:

```
self.view.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
    self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

Now i noticed that the `shouldAutorotate` method is called only once when the view is created the first time, i guess it should be like that. All of my controllers are subclassing `UIViewController`

I don't know what else to do. Some help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: how do you display the tab bar controller? could you show the code?

Comment: You are not alone. I have had [similar problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969624/ios-iphone-ipad-sdk-application-not-changing-orientation). Although I am yet to receive an answer.

Comment: like this `[self.window addSubview:rootController.view];` in the app delegate. Where rootController is an `IBOutlet`

Comment: Huh? Should rootController not be an `IBOutlet`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one

u have to use this all of ur Viewcontrollers in tabbarcontroller.

change this

```
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

to

```
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

self.view.autoresizesSubviews = YES;

self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

Comment: that does not work neither. I have support for all orientations in my infoPlist as well.

Comment: u have to use this all of ur Viewcontrollers in tabbarcontroller.

Comment: i already have. I have NavigationControllers to navigate through the views that are in the tabbar.

Comment: Ok. Something is really wrong with my project. I created a tabbar based project just to try it and the rotating worked. So, my application was firstly created as a Window based application, then i added the code to have a tabbar available in all the views. Maybe i'm missing something else

Comment: hi please give me ur mainwindow nib detail screanshot with all arrow opened and let me know

Comment: ur tabbarcontroller has totally four view(controllers).

first start viewcontroller


search view controller

courses view controller

my courses view controller

in above all of .m file should orientatin method should be like my code.


then above not worked then
 
first startviewcontroller should be deleted.


or

if use the startviewcontroller then select startviewcontroller then press cmd+4 then checkout class name.

Comment: You were right. I deleted StartViewController and it's working, the question is why? Because i can't afford to delete it. I'm using xcode4 so when i press cmd+4 it brings me to Issue Navigator window. What class name are you telling me to check out?

Comment: cmd+shift+L  then cmd + 4. then see class.like this checkout cmd+1 see nibname is set properly

Comment: If what you mean is that i should check which class is assigned to the StartViewController.xib it says StartViewController under Custom Class under the Identity inspector

Comment: i've already done that: `self.view.autoresizesSubviews = YES;

self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
` in the viewDidLoad method

Comment: Problem fixed. I had UIViewController intead of StartViewController (the one i created) under Identity Inspector. Thanks a lot for taking your time to help me.

Comment: welcome and for instant help http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/682/conversation/do-u-want-instant-help-for-ur-question-or-r-u-new-bee-to-iphone-ipad-develop